# Database connection is closed in spring boot app when connecting to Azure MSSQL DB if we kept idle for sometime

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

we have a multitenant architecture(same application connecting to different db's in azure based upon headers) spring boot application which interacts with azure mssql db for fetching records and deployed in azure app service.

It is working fine when we access the records through endpoint urls of spring boot rest service but if we kept idle for sometime it is throwing the below exception.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2392) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2376) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:1916) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.flush(IOBuffer.java:4301) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writePacket(IOBuffer.java:4202) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.endMessage(IOBuffer.java:3206) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7959) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7945) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2488) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2493) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:2633) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar!/:5.2.9.Final]
    ... 62 common frames omitted


Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:724) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:2946) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:2585) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1521) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

**Datasource configurations**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class MultiTenantConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc");  


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource multiTenantDataSource() {
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        Map<Object,Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<Object,Object>();

        String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]*)\\-([a-z]{3}+)");
        OperationsKeyVault opv = new OperationsKeyVault();
        String keyVaultName = System.getenv("KEYVAULT_NAME");
        for (String profile : profiles) {

            Matcher m = p.matcher(profile);
            if (!m.matches()) {
                continue;
            }

            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new DataSourceBuilder(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

            String tenantId = m.group(2);

            dataSourceBuilder
            .driverClassName(opv.GetSecret(keyVaultName, "mlsi-datasource-driver-class-name", "application/json"))
            .url(opv.GetSecret(keyVaultName, "mlsi-"+ tenantId + "-jdbc-url", "application/json"))
            .username(opv.GetSecret(keyVaultName, "mlsi-"+ tenantId + "-jdbc-username", "application/json"))
            .password(opv.GetSecret(keyVaultName, "mlsi-"+ tenantId + "-jdbc-password", "application/json"));

            resolvedDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSourceBuilder.build());           
        }

        MultiTenantDataSource dataSource = new MultiTenantDataSource();
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(resolvedDataSources.get("fth"));
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Repository configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.mls.feature.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "featureEntityManagerFactory")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(MultiTenantConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("com.example.mls.feature")
public class FeatureConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="multiTenantDataSource")
    private DataSource multiTenantDataSource;

    @Bean(name="featureEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public EntityManagerFactory featureEntityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.mls.feature.model");
        factory.setDataSource(multiTenantDataSource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
                config.exposeIdsFor(BaseUuidEntity.class, Recipient.class, NotificationRecipient.class);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since azure mssql database have 4mins connection timeout which cannot be altered, we also tried several properties below for autoreconnect

```
spring.datasource.core.validation-query==SELECT 1
spring.datasource.core.validation-interval=10000
spring.datasource.core.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.core.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.core.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=100000
spring.datasource.core.max-age=120000
```

We also tried both hikari and tomcat connection pools

So please help with this issue

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you even have a connection idling? General rule of thumb with databases: connect as late as possible, get your data, disconnect immediately.

Comment: we are using spring data jpa so we are not handling the connection and disconnection from db it is spring data jpa's task and we dont know how it is doing.

Comment: @madhankumar you are in control of what jpa does for you... There are properties that could let jpa know how many max,min and idle connections a db pool can have...

Comment: hi, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your properties are wrong.There is no *core* in property name. Here is the correct one for example.

```
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1 
spring.datasource.validation-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.validation-interval=180000
```